# SQL query WHERE string LIKE field

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I want to retrieve records which has arist name is Lata Mangeshkar  from up_song table which has artist column,
And  records like 1.Lata Mangeshkar 2. Lata Mangeshkar,sunidhi chuhan 3.Mohit chuhan, Ashaji ,Lata Mangeshkar.

song.aspx

```
    string lata = hlinklata.Text;
    hlinklata.NavigateUrl = "DisplayList.aspx?name=" + lata;
```

Displylist.aspx

```
     lblheader.Text = Request.QueryString["name"];

    String sql = "SELECT  title, song_id, movie_name, size FROM up_song WHERE  artist  LIKE  '%"+  lblheader.Text +" %' ";
    adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adpt.Fill(ds, "title");
    var last6Uploaded = ds.Tables["title"].AsEnumerable().OrderByDescending(r => r.Field<int>("song_id"));
    foreach (DataRow row in last6Uploaded)
    {

        int songID = row.Field<int>("song_id");
        HyperLink hl = new HyperLink(); 
        hl.ID = "hyperlink" + songID;
        string title = row.Field<string>("title");
        hl.Text = title;
        hl.NavigateUrl = "Downloadpage.aspx?name=" + title;
        hl.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        Paneltitle.Controls.Add(hl);
        Paneltitle.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>"));
    }
```

Comment: what is the problem or what is the error that you got

Comment: What is the problem? Seems fine to me...

Comment: is the problem in the sql query or the c# code and why you are using the lambda experssion as you can do every thing in your sql query

Comment: You can use linq query easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the issue is that you have an extra space after the inserted text in the SQL.  This means that you are effectively searching for "lblheader.text " (with a space after it) everytime, which I doubt is what you want.

In the SQL statement , change

`LIKE '%"+  lblheader.Text +" %' ";`

To

`LIKE  '%"+  lblheader.Text +"%' ";`

**On a separate issue**

The code above is subject to SQL Injection which is a major security issue for your application.  Read more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection